# TLS Implementation Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, ssl

I am trying to implement TLS client in a Silverlight XMPP application.

I found a nice documentation about TLS at [tools.ietf.org](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), there are a good explanation of structures, but I can't find an explanations of how to convert these strunctures into a raw message (bytes).

Here is for example a [ClientHello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2) message.

Can anyone share some tips or workarounds, or at least an example of how the ClientHello message should look in bytes?

I tried to sniff it out using WireShark, but it does not show the whole picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something is in full .NET Framework, and does not present in Silverlight, the first option for you is to go to Mono code base and find a way to port it,

https://github.com/mono/mono

As most Mono class library code is licensed under MIT/X11, it is safe to reuse them.

Starting from scratch like you did is not recommended if you've never done similar things before.

Answer (score 0):

TLS is not a trivial thing to implement. Unless you have specific reasons to do this, it's wiser to use existing implementation. You can use Mono as suggested above and port its code, or you can use SSL/TLS classes of our SecureBlackbox library, which is available for Silverlight as well, and doesn't require any extra coding from you.

Comment: Is there a sample of how to use the SecureBlackbox classes with Silverlight 5 and TLS 1.2? I installed SecureBlackbox and there are no samples included for SL and TLS. I am particularly interested in how to configure the app to use the protocol and how to secure outgoing SOAP and REST messages.

Comment: @GPicazo For technical support options please see https://www.eldos.com/sbb/support-tech.php . Thank you.